# How to run two sites with single domain on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Sorry! I don't know that the question I am asking have a logic or not.

I am not able  to figure out what to do. I am stuck up from yesterday.

Make a multi-site network or customize my wp theme.

So what do I mean.

I want my main website and my landing website to be on same domain but my landing page should be in with subdirectories.

**for example:**

```
My main website domain is something like this :  mywebsitemain.com

and

My landing page website is as follows : mywebsitemain.com/landing-page
```

**Conclusion**

```
1. Single domain
2. Two websites
```

Is this is achieve able without using multisite or not. If yes or no then how.

Comment: Follow this document of wordpress for creating network to do multisite. https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: @ShashankSharma I have checked it but there would be any way to do this without multisite

Comment: Other way to doing that is, you can simply create a directory and install new wordpress setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way.
1)Setup two wordpress
First is in the root directory("main wesite domain")
And second one steup on the ("landing-page") directory. and when steup the wordpress then you should make both the table prefix different.

2)Make wordpress network 
Check url : https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network